# Docker Python set utf-8 locale

Tags: python, docker, utf-8

I am trying to run my python file that first reads a string in Chinese language and print it.

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:2.7-onbuild
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

This is my python file:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    import jieba
    s = "我来到北京清华大学"
    s = s.decode('utf-8')
    print type(s), s
```

I then run :

`docker build -t python-example .`

`docker run python-example`

Error i got: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-8: ordinal not in range(128)`

When i run it locally, it works fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python, Docker - 'ascii' codec can't encode character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52065842/python-docker-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I ran into the same issue while I was deploying a Django application with supervisor and gunicorn.

What fixed it was to add the following line to my supervisor config file:

```
environment=LANG="es_ES.utf8", LC_ALL="es_ES.UTF-8", LC_LANG="es_ES.UTF-8"
```

For your case make sure that the chinese locale that you want to print is available and installed in your docker container. This [blog](http://www.roadsi.de/locales-on-ubuntu-in-docker.html) describes how to do it: 
example dockerfile (use the chinese locale instead of en_CA.UTF-8):

```
FROM ubuntu:15.10
MAINTAINER Mobify <ops@mobify.com>

RUN apt-get -qq update && \
    apt-get -q -y upgrade && \
    apt-get install -y sudo curl wget locales && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Ensure that we always use UTF-8 and with Canadian English locale
RUN locale-gen en_CA.UTF-8

COPY ./default_locale /etc/default/locale
RUN chmod 0755 /etc/default/locale

ENV LC_ALL=en_CA.UTF-8
ENV LANG=en_CA.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE=en_CA.UTF-8
```

hopefully this leads you into the right direction.

Comment: This is for ubuntu, mine is for a python image though

Comment: according to this github issue tracker: https://github.com/docker-library/python/issues/69 you could also try this: docker run -e PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 does this work?

Comment: Yea it worked!! thank you! the full code: `docker run -e PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 python-example`

Answer (score 25):

### Short version

Put this in your `Dockerfile`:

```
ENV PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8
```

or as mentioned in the comments above pass it on the command line:

```
docker run -e PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 my-python-image some-command
```

### Long version:

When you start the Python interpreter, Python has to set up `stdout` in order to send output to your terminal. On your modern O/S, your terminal probably reports that it supports UTF-8 or some other advanced encoding. You can see what encoding is used by running this command:

```
$ python -c 'import sys; print(sys.stdout.encoding)'
UTF-8
```

When you run a docker container, the environment variables Python would expect to use a more advanced encoding are not present, and so Python will fall back to a basic character set to ensure compatibility. You can verify this by running the same command in your container:

```
$ docker run my-python-image python -c 'import sys; print(sys.stdout.encoding)'
ANSI_X3.4-1968
```

When we pass `PYTHONIOENCODING` we see the `sys.stdout.encoding` is set appropriately:

```
$ docker run -e PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8 my-python-image python -c 'import sys; print(sys.stdout.encoding)'
UTF-8
```

Read about `PYTHONIOENCODING` in [the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING). [This answer also goes into great detail about encoding/decoding and `stdout`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44344458/why-does-locale-getpreferredencoding-return-ansi-x3-4-1968-instead-of-utf-8).

Comment: On Ubuntu Bionic, this only works when the `locales` package is installed first.

Answer (score 2):

I add the below command in my docker file：

```
RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG='en_US.UTF-8' LANGUAGE='en_US:en' LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8'
```

then build/rebuild docker images, you'd better add this in the base image.

Answer (score 0):

```
RUN set -e \
  && locale-gen en_CA en_CA.UTF-8 \
  && update-locale LC_ALL=en_CA.UTF-8 LANG=en_CA.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

For posterity's sake, none of the other answers here worked for me, but I was able to get it working from a base Python image by installing locales, manually editing /etc/locales.gen, and then running locale-gen.

`locale-gen en_US.UTF-8` didn't work for me. As far as I can tell, locale-gen ignores any arguments after it, and just references those enabled lines in /etc/locale.gen

Assuming you've already run apt-get update

Install the locales package

`RUN apt-get install locales`

Enable the locale you want to use, in my case en_US.UTF-8

`RUN sed -i 's/# en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/g' /etc/locale.gen`

Regenerate all enabled locales

`RUN locale-gen`

Set required environment variables

`ENV LANG="en_US.UTF-8" LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"`