# Why does locale.getpreferredencoding() return 'ANSI_X3.4-1968' instead of 'UTF-8'?

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

Whenever I try to read UTF-8 encoded text files, using `open(file_name, encoding='utf-8')`, I always get an error saying ASCII codec can't decode some characters (eg. when using `for line in f: print(line)`)

```
Python 3.5.3 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:11:04)
[GCC 6.3.0 20170118] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import locale
>>> locale.getpreferredencoding()
'ANSI_X3.4-1968'
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getfilesystemencoding()
'ascii'
>>>
```

and `locale` command prints:

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE=en_HK.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem. For me, initially the environtment variable `LANG` was not set (you can check this by running `env`)

```
$ python3 -c 'import locale; print(locale.getdefaultlocale())'
(None, None)
$ python3 -c 'import locale; print(locale.getpreferredencoding())'
ANSI_X3.4-1968
```

The available locales for me was (on a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 Docker image):

```
$ locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
```

So i picked the utf-8 one:

```
$ export LANG="C.UTF-8"
```

And then things work

```
$ python3 -c 'import locale; print(locale.getdefaultlocale())'
('en_US', 'UTF-8')
$ python3 -c 'import locale; print(locale.getpreferredencoding())'
UTF-8
```

---

If you pick a locale that is not avaiable, such as

```
export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

it will *not* work:

```
$ python3 -c 'import locale; print(locale.getdefaultlocale())'
('en_US', 'UTF-8')
$ python3 -c 'import locale; print(locale.getpreferredencoding())'
ANSI_X3.4-1968
```

and this is why `locale` is giving the error messages:

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution :

```
import locale 

locale.getpreferredencoding = lambda: "UTF-8"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by running the following:

```
apt install locales-all
```

Comment: I had this issue with Docker scratch image. So I needed to copy `/usr/lib/locale` from another image

Answer (score 0):

By default, Python tries to honor the Unix locale system, including the `LC_ALL`, `LC_CTYPE`, and `LANG` environment variables. In theory, standards are good, but in my experience these variables only cause problems. They're sometimes set to ridiculous values, like non-UTF-8 character sets, for no good reason. Then Python throws errors when `print()`ing non-ASCII text.

You can fix this by finding out what these environment variables are set to, and why, and change them to something Unicode-capable. But system configuration can be a can of worms.

**Python 3.7 and later offer these two quick fixes:**

- Set `PYTHONUTF8=1` in the environment when running this script.
- If you can't do that, then early in your script, force `stdout` to be UTF-8 by doing

  ```
  import sys

  sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')
  ```