# python based Dockerfile throws locale.Error: unsupported locale setting

Tags: python, dockerfile, locale

I have a problem with passing the host's (Centos7) locales to the python3 docker image. Only the following locales end up in the image, even though I used the suggestion described in the link below:

```
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
```

[Why does locale.getpreferredencoding() return 'ANSI_X3.4-1968' instead of 'UTF-8'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44344458/why-does-locale-getpreferredencoding-return-ansi-x3-4-1968-instead-of-utf-8/59632904#59632904)

My Dockerfile has:

```
FROM python:3.7.5
ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8
WORKDIR /data
ADD ./requirements.txt /data/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /data
CMD [ "python3", "./test.py" ]
```

When I run this command:

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'ru_RU')
```

it throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "./test.py", line 10, in <module>
        locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'ru_RU')
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/locale.py", line 608, in setlocale
        return _setlocale(category, locale)
    locale.Error: unsupported locale setting
```

If I set

```
ENV LANG ru_RU.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL ru_RU.UTF-8
```

Then I get:

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_COLLATE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale.getdefaultlocale ('ru_RU', 'UTF-8')
locale.getpreferredencoding UTF-8
Exception: unsupported locale setting
```

Please, explain how can I add a ru_RU locale into the python image?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

What I would do for Debian based docker image:

```
FROM python:3.7.5

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y locales && \
    sed -i -e 's/# ru_RU.UTF-8 UTF-8/ru_RU.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen && \
    dpkg-reconfigure --frontend=noninteractive locales

ENV LANG ru_RU.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL ru_RU.UTF-8
```

and then in python:

```py
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'ru_RU.UTF-8')
```

Comment: Thank you. You meant yum install -y locales since I have Centos. Are you sure if it is possible to call yum in python based image? I have FROM python, but not FROM centos.

Comment: It is not a problem. After all, it is still a Linux distro.

Comment: I've tested my solution with Debian-based image. Let me know if it works for Centos

Comment: From the dockerfile that you posted, it looks like you are using this image https://hub.docker.com/layers/python/library/python/3.7.5/images/sha256-75ac684e1b4ec87174779576fa6181034e3a069ef879361fbaea04a74959a5f1 which  seems to be Debian-based. If that's true, my Dockerfile is correct and does not need extra edit

Comment: In other words `apt-get`, not `yum` :)

Comment: Thank you! This solved the problem. Now locales -a shows these ones in the image: C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
ru_RU.utf8

Comment: Great! Thanks for approving the anwser

Comment: Worked for ubuntu 20.04 docker image and de_DE locale.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who can't get the accepted answer to work with intended locales such as `en_IN.UTF-8`, be wary of spaces in your locale in `/etc/locale.gen`.

try this:

```
FROM python:3.8

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y locales && \
    sed -i -e 's/# en_IN UTF-8/en_IN UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen && \
    dpkg-reconfigure --frontend=noninteractive locales

ENV LANG en_IN.UTF-8
ENV LC_NUMERIC en_IN.UTF-8
```

After `dpkg-reconfigure`, the locale should be available as `en_IN.UTF-8`