# Brazilian locale currency error when running Python application with Docker

Tags: python, docker

I'm running a Python application with Docker and I faced this error when trying to call the currency method from locale

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/locale.py", line 273, in currency
reduto     |     raise ValueError("Currency formatting is not possible using "
reduto     | ValueError: Currency formatting is not possible using the 'C' locale.
```

When I use the currency method outside Docker, it works - probably because my operating system timezone is set to Brazilian timezone. But how can I fix it with Docker?

This is the line of code that triggers the error:

```py
locale.currency(float("%.2f" % pmt_value), grouping=True, symbol="R$"),
```

I don't know if it makes a difference but I'm using Docker 24.0.7, with Docker Compose version 3, on a Ubuntu 22.04.3.

Comment: What is your base image? Could you provide a [mre] including a Dockerfile?

Comment: You are most likely hitting an issue with an environment variable where you need to set `LC_ALL` in your image. Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59633558/python-based-dockerfile-throws-locale-error-unsupported-locale-setting