# Once again, UnicodeEncodeError (ascii codec can't encode)

Tags: python, django, unicode, cyrillic

I'm running python 3.6 + gunicorn + django 2.0.5 in docker container with some cyrillic project and that's what I see when I try to log cyrillic strings in console with Django.

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u0410' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Also this what happens in shell

```
Python 3.6.5 (default, May  3 2018, 10:08:28) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> :�ириллица
```

The same time, when i'm running python 3.5 outside docker container, everything is ok:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> Кириллица
```

Any ideas how to make python 3.6 inside docker work ok with cyrillic strings?

Comment: This is not a string, this is an identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` in the first line of your python code.

And in your `Dockerfile` add:

ENV PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8

Comment: didn't work :) Still print("\u041f\u043e\u0435\u0445\u0430\u043b\u0438")
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-6: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Maybe it can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43356982/docker-python-set-utf-8-locale

Comment: Thanks! ENV PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 - helped

Comment: I will edit my answer to include this. Please if you could, mark as solved.